# Extract device name (sda/sdb/etc) from file

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out if a given file is on an SSD drive or not by checking the rotational flag with:

```
cat /sys/block/sdx/queue/rotational
```

My program will be given a filename, and I'm wondering if there is a simple way to go from the filename to the device name. I can think of ways to hack it like processing the output of df, but am hoping for a more straightforward path.

Edit:
Alternatively, I'd accept just a quick way to benchmark read/writes to a disk of interest to see if it meets various benchmarks in python (ie sequential reads/writes are as fast as random reads/writes).

Comment: You'd probably want to actually parse `/proc/mounts` instead of the output of `df`.

Comment: @BillLynch Although that could be complicated significantly if, e.g. the file system that the given file is on is in an LVM2 LV that is a part of a VG that lives on a device-mapper device that is an encrypted block device based on an MD RAID10 device where one component is a partition on the device in question... There's not really enough info in the question to answer this reliably...

Comment: @twalberg It isn't a crazy convoluted setup, but it may be run on different systems with various disk setups. An alternative route I guess would be to ask what's a good way to quickly test random read/write speed with python to just benchmark it and figure out if the disk can handle parallel reads/writes at an adequate rate.

Comment: @Chrismit Well, the above isn't really a crazy convoluted setup - although it might sound like it. My point was there's not in the general case a completely reliable method to say "this file is on this disk" without knowing a lot more about the specific configuration. For a laptop or desktop, it's probably easier than an enterprise-class server with RAID and encryption, though...

Comment: @twalberg So the random access (ie duck typing your disks) seems the most robust to me.